# How can I use \belowcaptionskip with listing?

Tags: spacing, floats, minted

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% question regarding this code
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
% end

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{listing}[h]
\begin{verbatim}
1
2
3
4
\end{verbatim}
\caption{test}
\label{lst}
\end{listing}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{verbatim}
1
2
3
4
\end{verbatim}
\caption{test}
\label{ver}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Why does `\listing` ignore change of `\belowcaptionskip`? What can I change to make `listing` affected by it as in case of `figure`?
How can I make caption of `listing` be identical with caption of `figure` in every manner (like fontsize, which on my example is smaller in `figure`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mwrep` document class redefines the way `\caption` behaves for standard floats (i.e., `table` and `figure`); the `minted` package defines its `listing` environment using the features provided by the `float` package; as a result, the redefinition of `mwrep` doesn't apply to the `listings` environment; one way to solve the problem is to `\restyle` the `listing` float to use the settings that `mwrep` uses (in particular, `\captionsettings`); here's such an example illustrating this approach with a modified version of the `plain` float style as defined by the `float` package:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\floatc@plain[2]{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\captionsettings{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize \captionsettings{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2\par
    \else\hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}\fi\vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat{listing}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{listing}[h]
\begin{verbatim}
1
2
3
4
\end{verbatim}
\caption{test}
\label{lst}
\end{listing}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{verbatim}
1
2
3
4
\end{verbatim}
\caption{test}
\label{ver}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]